# How to reduce the size of a NetCDF in R?

Tags: raster, r, netcdf

I'm working with a large land cover file (~2.3 GB) saved in NetCDF format (it's the 2018 gridded map from [here](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/satellite-land-cover?tab=form)). My aim is to associate GPS points with this land cover data using R.

The problem is that R cannot allocate a vector of sufficient size to get at the land cover data types once I load it.

Is there a way to bound the data first (I want only the land cover from sub-Saharan Africa) before I try to manipulate it?

Here's my code so far with a failed attempt (based on [this tutorial](http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/week04-netCDF.html)):

```
#' load any packages
library(ncdf4)

# set path and filename
ncpath <- "C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\Science\\GIS\\Global Land Cover\\"
ncname <- "C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2018-v2.1.1"  
ncfname <- paste(ncpath, ncname, ".nc", sep="")
dname <- "lccs_class"

# open a netCDF file
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
print(ncin)

# get longitude and latitude
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lon")
nlon <- dim(lon)
head(lon)

lat <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lat")
nlat <- dim(lat)
head(lat)

print(c(nlon,nlat))

#' create a bounding box to work with a subset
LonIdx <- which( ncin$dim$lon$vals > 30 & ncin$dim$lon$vals < 32)
LatIdx <- which( ncin$dim$lat$vals > -27 & ncin$dim$lat$vals < -26)
MyVariable <- ncvar_get( ncin, dname)[ LonIdx, LatIdx] # THIS THROWS AN ERROR 
# 'Error: cannot allocate vector of size 31.3 Gb'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reading the whole dataset in and then subsetting it with R matrix subsetting, you can directly read only a subset of the NetCDF using the `start` and `count` options.

Here's an example with a test NetCDF:

My Lon and Lat indexes are:

```
> LonIdx
[1] 841 842 843 844 845 846 847 848
> LatIdx
[1] 93 94 95 96
```

If I read the full dataset in and subset I get this:

```
> Full <- ncvar_get( ncin, dname)[LatIdx,LonIdx]
> Full
           [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,] 17.9270401 15.430718 1.260737 3.2765274 1.6295669 0.9793988    0    0
[2,]  0.4018250  6.951360 3.520601 0.6627708 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0
[3,]  0.9412467  8.189851 6.139299 1.3281101 0.5528592 2.8608725    0    0
[4,]  3.6696143  9.101377 7.859358 9.9297428 5.7591023 4.4519467    0    0
```

To read a subset without reading the whole dataset, I want to start at the first value in the indexes and read the count of how many elements in the indexes. Like this:

```
> Part <- ncvar_get( ncin, dname, 
     start=c(LatIdx[1],LonIdx[1]),
     count=c(length(LatIdx),length(LonIdx)))
> Part
           [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,] 17.9270401 15.430718 1.260737 3.2765274 1.6295669 0.9793988    0    0
[2,]  0.4018250  6.951360 3.520601 0.6627708 0.0000000 0.0000000    0    0
[3,]  0.9412467  8.189851 6.139299 1.3281101 0.5528592 2.8608725    0    0
[4,]  3.6696143  9.101377 7.859358 9.9297428 5.7591023 4.4519467    0    0
>
```

Which looks the same as reading the other way.

I notice my lat and long are the other way round from yours - make sure you get things the right way round for your data set...